# MySQL join query on three tables which connected to each other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables like this:

**Animal**

```
| id | cat_id | horse_id | dog_id |
|:--:|:------:|:--------:|--------|
|  1 |   15   |    16    | 17     |
```

**Cat**

```
| id | lang_id |
|:--:|:-------:|
| 15 |   3716  |
```

**Horse**

```
| id | lang_id |
|:--:|:-------:|
| 16 |   3717  |
```

**Dog**

```
| id | lang_id |
|:--:|:-------:|
| 17 |   3718  |
```

**Language**

```
|  id  |      en        |
|:----:|:--------------:|
| 3716 | BRAVE LEGEND   |
| 3717 | N Rawiller     |
| 3718 | DRAGON GENERAL |
```

I want to get all the animals `en` name from `Language` table through each animal's table `lang_id`. It would be like by using `Animal`: `cat_id` -> `Cat`: `lang_id` -> `Language`: `en`. The final results would be like:

```
| animal_id |   cat_name   | horse_name |    dog_name    |
|:---------:|:------------:|:----------:|:--------------:|
|     1     | BRAVE LEGEND | N Rawiller | DRAGON GENERAL |
```

I am trying to use this:

```
select animal.id, lang.* from animal 
left join cat on animal.cat_id = cat.id
left join horse on animal.horse_id = horse.id
left join dog on animal.dog_id = dog.id
left join lang on cat.lang_id = lang.id or (horse.lang_id = lang.id) or (dog.lang_id = lang.id)
where animal.id = 1
```

But I can't get `cat_name`, `dog_name`, `horse_name` because it's all coming from the same `Language` table.

Comment: You has to perform 3 left joins to lang table instead of ussing or in On statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query:

You need to `JOIN` lang table multiple times, using one `JOIN` with multiple OR will not give you desired result,

```
SELECT animal.id, lang.en as cat_name,l1.en as horse_name,l2.en as dog_name 
FROM animal 
      LEFT JOIN cat ON animal.cat_id = cat.id
      LEFT JOIN horse ON animal.horse_id = horse.id
      LEFT JOIN dog ON animal.dog_id = dog.id
      LEFT JOIN lang ON cat.lang_id = lang.id 
      LEFT JOIN lang l1 ON horse.lang_id = l1.id 
      LEFT JOIN lang l2 ON dog.lang_id = l2.id
WHERE animal.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select animal.id, lang1.cat_name, lang2.horse_name, lang3.dog_name  
from animal 
left join cat on animal.cat_id = cat.id
left join horse on animal.horse_id = horse.id
left join dog on animal.dog_id = dog.id
left join lang AS lang1 on cat.lang_id = lang1.id 
left join lang AS lang2 ON horse.lang_id = lang2.id 
left join lang AS lang3 ON (dog.lang_id = lang3.id)
where animal.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
SELECT a.id, lang1.en  as cat_name,lang2.en as horse_name,lang3.en as dog_name
FROM  `animal` a
LEFT JOIN cat c ON c.id = a.cat_id 
LEFT JOIN LANGUAGE l on l.id=c.lang_id
LEFT JOIN dog d ON d.id = a.dog_id
LEFT JOIN horse h ON h.id = a.horse_id
LEFT JOIN language lang1 ON c.lang_id=lang1.id
LEFT JOIN language lang2 ON h.lang_id=lang2.id
LEFT JOIN language lang3 ON d.lang_id=lang3.id
```